# How to execute a PowerShell function several times in parallel?

Tags: powershell, asynchronous

I'm not sure whether to call this a need for multi-threading, job-based, or async, but basically I have a Powershell script function that takes several parameters and I need to call it several times with different parameters and have these run in parallel.

Currently, I call the function like this:

```
Execute "param1" "param2" "param3" "param4"
```

How can I call this multiple times without waiting for each call to Execute return to the caller?

Currently I'm running v2.0 but I can update if necessary

**EDIT:** here's what I have so far, which doesn't work:

```
$cmd = {
    param($vmxFilePath,$machineName,$username,$password,$scriptTpath,$scriptFile,$uacDismissScript,$snapshotName)
    Execute $vmxFilePath $machineName $username $password $scriptTpath $scriptFile $uacDismissScript $snapshotName
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $cmd -ArgumentList $vmxFilePath, $machineName, $username $password, $scriptTpath, $scriptFile, $uacDismissScript, $snapshotName
```

I get an error:

> cannot convert 'system.object[]' to the type 'system.management.automation.scriptblock' required by parameter 'initializationscript'. specified method is not supported

**EDIT2:** I've modified my script but I still get the error mentioned above. Here's my mod:

```
$cmd = {
    param($vmxFilePath,$machineName,$username,$password,$scriptTpath,$scriptFile,$uacDismissScript,$snapshotName)
    Execute $vmxFilePath $machineName $username $password $scriptTpath $scriptFile $uacDismissScript $snapshotName
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $cmd -ArgumentList $vmxFilePath, $machineName, $username $password, $scriptTpath, $scriptFile, $uacDismissScript, $snapshotName
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

No update necessary for this. Define a script block and use `Start-Job` to run the script block as many times as necessary. Example:

```
$cmd = {
  param($a, $b)
  Write-Host $a $b
}

$foo = "foo"

1..5 | ForEach-Object {
  Start-Job -ScriptBlock $cmd -ArgumentList $_, $foo
}
```

The script block takes 2 parameters `$a` and `$b` which are passed by the `-ArgumentList` option. In the example above, the assignments are `$_` → `$a` and `$foo` → `$b`. `$foo` is just an example for a configurable, but static parameter.

Run `Get-Job | Remove-Job` at some point to remove the finished jobs from the queue (or `Get-Job | % { Receive-Job $_.Id; Remove-Job $_.Id }` if you want to retrieve the output).

Comment: I'm still having a hard time mapping your solution to get my own script to work. I'm going to start simple, and just try to get Start-Job to run my scriptblock with the arguments which my custom function, Execute, requires. Maybe you can expand? Is $foo a parameter in addition to the ones specificed by param($a, $b) ?

Comment: I see now, thanks. I still get the error though. If you're unsure what this could be I'll just create separate post/question.

Comment: For testing purposes replace the call of your `Execute()` function with code that just echoes the parameters. Does that work? If it does, the problem lies with the function you want to call.

Answer (score 33):

Here's a quick bogus scriptblock for the purpose of testing:

```
$Code = {
    param ($init)
    $start = Get-Date
    (1..30) | % { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; $init +=1 }
    $stop = Get-Date
    Write-Output "Counted from $($init - 30) until $init in $($stop - $start)."
}
```

This scriptblock can then be passed on to `Start-Job`, with for example 3 parameters (10, 15, 35)

```
$jobs = @()
(10,15,35) | % { $jobs += Start-Job -ArgumentList $_ -ScriptBlock $Code }

Wait-Job -Job $jobs | Out-Null
Receive-Job -Job $jobs
```

This creates 3 jobs, assign them to the `$jobs` variable, runs them in parallel and then waits for these 3 jobs to finish, and retrieves the results:

```
Counted from 10 until 40 in 00:00:30.0147167.
Counted from 15 until 45 in 00:00:30.0057163.
Counted from 35 until 65 in 00:00:30.0067163.
```

This did not take 90 seconds to execute, only 30.

One of the tricky parts is to provide `-Argumentlist` to `Start-Job`, and include a `param()` block inside the ScriptBlock.  Otherwise, your values are never seen by the scriptblock.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an alternative which may be faster than invoking jobs if the function is not a long running one. Max thread is 25 and I'm only invoking this function 10 times, so I expect my total runtime to be 5 seconds.  You can wrap Measure-Command around the 'results=' statement to view stats.

Example:

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    Param ( [int]$RunNumber )
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5   
    Return $RunNumber
}
$runNumbers = @(1..10)
$MaxThreads = 25
$runspacePool = [RunspaceFactory ]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $MaxThreads)
$runspacePool.Open()
$pipeLines = foreach($num in $runNumbers){
    $pipeline = [powershell]::Create()
    $pipeline.RunspacePool = $runspacePool
    $pipeline.AddScript($ScriptBlock)    | Out-Null   
    $pipeline.AddArgument($num)  | Out-Null
    $pipeline | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'AsyncResult' -Value $pipeline.BeginInvoke() -PassThru 
}
#obtain results as they come.
$results =  foreach($pipeline in $pipeLines){
    $pipeline.EndInvoke($pipeline.AsyncResult )
}
#cleanup code.
$pipeLines | % { $_.Dispose()}
$pipeLines = $null
if ( $runspacePool ) { $runspacePool.Close()}
#your results
$results
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry that everyone missed your issue - I know it is far too late now, but...

This error is caused because you are missing a comma between $username and $password in your list.

You can test it out with this snippet, which I modelled off of the previous answers:

```
$cmd = {
  param($a, $b, $c, $d)
}
$foo = "foo"
$bar = "bar"
start-job -scriptblock $cmd -ArgumentList "a", $foo, $bar, "gold" #added missing comma for this to work
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a very versitile function to do this for you, and unlike the other answers you dont need to rejig your code to get it to work.
Just pass your function as a parameter to `Async` and pipe your input in, each item on the pipeline will run your `scriptblock` in parallel asynchronously, and emit them as each one is completed.

For your question specifically it would look something like this

```powershell
@(
    @{vmxFilePath='a';machineName='b';username='c';password='d';scriptTpath='e';scriptFile='f';uacDismissScript='g';snapshotName'h'},
    @{vmxFilePath='i';machineName='j';username='k';password='l';scriptTpath='m';scriptFile='n';uacDismissScript='o';snapshotName'p'}
    ...
) `
| Async `
    -Func { Process {
        Execute $_.vmxFilePath $_.machineName $_.username $_.password $_.scriptTpath $_.scriptFile $_.uacDismissScript $_.snapshotName
    } }
```

On top of this my function supports not only automatic construction of [`[powershell]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) (@binarySalt's answer) but also [`Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.job?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0)s (utilised in @Joost's, but dont use these as they are much slower than runspaces) and [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=netframework-4.8)s if you're using other people's code that already spawn them (use the `-AsJob` flag, which I explain at the bottom of this answer).

---

So, that's not useful for new visitors to this question, lets do something more demonstrable that you can run on your machine and see real-world results.
Take this simple code for example, it just takes in some test data for websites and checks if they're up.

```powershell
$in=TestData | ?{ $_.proto -eq 'tcp' }
$in `
| %{
    $WarningPreference='SilentlyContinue'
    $_ `
    | Add-Member `
        -PassThru `
        -MemberType NoteProperty `
        -Name result `
        -Value $(Test-NetConnection `
            -ComputerName $_.address `
            -Port $_.port `
            -InformationLevel Quiet
        )
} `
| Timer -name 'normal' `
| Format-Table
```

[image]

Here's the test data, just a good few of the same websites on repeat.
And also a timing function to see how performant it is.

```powershell
Function TestData {
    1..20 | %{
        [PsCustomObject]@{proto='tcp'  ; address='www.w3.org'            ; port=443},
        [PsCustomObject]@{proto='https'; address='www.w3.org'            ; port=443},
        [PsCustomObject]@{proto='icmp' ; address='www.w3.org'            ;         },
        [PsCustomObject]@{proto='tcp'  ; address='developer.mozilla.org' ; port=443},
        [PsCustomObject]@{proto='https'; address='developer.mozilla.org' ; port=443},
        [PsCustomObject]@{proto='icmp' ; address='developer.mozilla.org' ;         },
        [PsCustomObject]@{proto='tcp'  ; address='help.dottoro.com'      ; port=80 },
        [PsCustomObject]@{proto='http' ; address='help.dottoro.com'      ; port=80 },
        [PsCustomObject]@{proto='icmp' ; address='help.dottoro.com'      ;         }
    }
}

Function Timer {
    Param ($name)
    Begin {
        $timer=[system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
    }
    Process { $_ }
    End {
        @(
            $name,
            ' '
            [math]::Floor($timer.Elapsed.TotalMinutes),
            ':',
            ($timer.Elapsed.Seconds -replace '^(.)$','0$1')
        ) -join '' | Out-Host
    }
}
```

Okay, 15seconds, so how much faster can this get if we use `Async`?
And how much do we have to change to get it to work?

```powershell
$in=TestData | ?{ $_.proto -eq 'tcp' }
$in `
| Async `
    -Expected $in.Count `
    -Func { Process {
        $WarningPreference='SilentlyContinue'
        $_ `
        | Add-Member `
            -PassThru `
            -MemberType NoteProperty `
            -Name result `
            -Value $(Test-NetConnection `
                -ComputerName $_.address `
                -Port $_.port `
                -InformationLevel Quiet
            )
    } } `
| Timer -name 'async' `
| Format-Table
```

It looks basically identical..
Okay, what's the speed?

[image]

Wow, cut it by two thirds!
Not only that, but because we know how many items are in the pipeline I wrote in some smarts to give you a progressbar and an ETA

[image]

[Don't believe me? Have a video](https://i.imgur.com/TepGpHP.mp4)
Or run the code yourself :)

```powershell
#Requires -Version 5.1

#asynchronously run a pool of tasks,
#and aggregate the results back into a synchronous output
#without waiting to pool all input before seeing the first result
Function Async { Param(
    #maximum permitted simultaneous background tasks
    [int]$BatchSize=[int]$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS * 3,
    #the task that accepts input on a pipe to execute in the background
    [scriptblock]$Func,
    #because your task is in a subshell you wont have access to your outer scope,
    #you may pass them in here
    [array]$ArgumentList=@(),
    [System.Collections.IDictionary]$Parameters=@{},
    #the title of the progress bar
    [string]$Name='Processing',
    #your -Func may return a [Job] instead of being backgrounded itself,
    #if so it must return @(job;input;args)
    #optionally job may be a [scriptblock] to be backgrounded, or a [Task]
    [switch]$AsJob,
    #if you know the number of tasks ahead of time,
    #providing it here will have the progress bar show an ETA
    [int]$Expected,
    #outputs of this stream will be @(job;input) where job is the result
    [switch]$PassThru,
    #the time it takes to give up on one job type if there are others waiting
    [int]$Retry=5
)   
    Begin {
        $ArgumentList=[Array]::AsReadOnly($ArgumentList)
        $Parameters=$Parameters.GetEnumerator() `
        | &{
            Begin { $params=[ordered]@{} }
            Process { $params.Add($_.Key, $_.Value) }
            End { $params.AsReadOnly() }
        }
        #the currently running background tasks
        $running=@{}
        $counts=[PSCustomObject]@{
            completed=0;
            jobs=0;
            tasks=0;
            results=0;
        }
        #a lazy attempt at uniquely IDing this instance for Write-Progress
        $asyncId=Get-Random
        #a timer for Write-Progress
        $timer=[system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()

        $pool=[RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $BatchSize)
        $pool.Open()

        #called whenever we want to update the progress bar
        Function Progress { Param($Reason)
            #calculate ETA if applicable
            $eta=-1
            $total=[math]::Max(1, $counts.completed + $running.Count)
            if ($Expected) {
                $total=[math]::Max($total, $Expected)
                if ($counts.completed) {
                    $eta=`
                        ($total - $counts.completed) * `
                        $timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds / `
                        $counts.completed
                }
            }

            $Reason=Switch -regex ($Reason) {
                '^done$'   { "Finishing up the final $($running.Count) jobs." }
                '^(do|next)$' { "
                    Running
                     $($running.Count)
                     jobs concurrently.
                     $(@('Adding','Waiting to add')[!($Reason -eq 'do')])
                     job #
                    $($counts.completed + $running.Count + 1)
                " -replace '\r?\n\t*','' }
                Default { "
                    Running $($running.Count) jobs concurrently.
                     Emitting
                     $($counts.completed)
                    $(@{1='st';2='nd';3='rd'}[$counts.completed % 10] -replace '^$','th')
                     result.
                " -replace '\r?\n\t*','' }
            }

            Write-Progress `
                -Id $asyncId `
                -Activity $Name `
                -SecondsRemaining $eta `
                -Status ("
                    $($counts.completed)
                     jobs completed in
                     $([math]::Floor($timer.Elapsed.TotalMinutes))
                    :
                    $($timer.Elapsed.Seconds -replace '^(.)$','0$1')
                " -replace '\r?\n\t*','') `
                -CurrentOperation $Reason `
                -PercentComplete (100 * $counts.completed / $total)
        }

        #called with the [Job]'s that have completed 
        Filter Done {
            ++$counts.completed
            $out=$running.Item($_.Id)
            $running.Remove($_.Id)

            Progress

            $out.job=`
            if ($_ -is [System.Management.Automation.Job]) {
                --$counts.jobs
                $_ | Receive-Job
            }
            elseif ($_.pwsh) {
                --$counts.results
                try {
                    $_.pwsh.EndInvoke($_)
                }
                catch {
                    #[System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException]
                    $_.Exception.InnerException
                }
                finally {
                    $_.pwsh.Dispose()
                }
            }
            elseif ($_.IsFaulted) {
                --$counts.tasks
                #[System.AggregateException]
                $_.Exception.InnerException
            }
            else {
                --$counts.tasks
                $_.Result
            }

            if ($PassThru) {
                $out
            }
            else {
                $out.job
            }
        }

        $isJob={
            $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.Job]
        }
        $isTask={
            $_ -is [System.Threading.Tasks.Task]
        }
        $isResult={
            $_ -is [IAsyncResult]
        }
        $isFinished={
            $_.IsCompleted -or `
            (
                $_.JobStateInfo.State -gt 1 -and
                $_.JobStateInfo.State -ne 6 -and
                $_.JobStateInfo.State -ne 8
            )
        }
        $handle={
            $_.AsyncWaitHandle
        }

        Function Jobs { Param($Filter)
            $running.Values | %{ $_.job } | ? $Filter
        }

        #called whenever we need to wait for at least one task to completed
        #outputs the completed tasks
        Function Wait { Param([switch]$Finishing)
            #if we are at the max background tasks this instant
            while ($running.Count -ge $BatchSize) {
                Progress -Reason @('done','next')[!$Finishing]

                $value=@('jobs', 'tasks', 'results') `
                | %{ $counts.($_) } `
                | measure -Maximum -Sum
                $wait=if ($value.Maximum -lt $value.Sum) {
                    $Retry
                }
                else {
                    -1
                }

                $value=Switch -exact ($value.Maximum) {
                    $counts.jobs {
                        (Wait-Job `
                            -Any `
                            -Job (Jobs -Filter $isJob) `
                            -Timeout $wait
                        ).Count -lt 1
                        break
                    }
                    Default {
                        [System.Threading.WaitHandle]::WaitAny(
                            (Jobs -Filter $handle | % $handle),
                            [math]::Max($wait * 1000, -1)
                        ) -eq [System.Threading.WaitHandle]::WaitTimeout
                        break
                    }
                }

                (Jobs -Filter $isFinished) | Done
            }
        }
    }

    #accepts inputs to spawn a new background task with
    Process {
        Wait
        Progress -Reason 'do'

        $run=[PSCustomObject]@{
            input=$_;
            job=$Func;
            args=$ArgumentList;
            params=$Parameters;
        }
        if ($AsJob) {
            $run.job=$NULL
            Invoke-Command `
                -ScriptBlock $Func `
                -ArgumentList @($run) `
            | Out-Null
        }

        if ($run.job | % $isJob) {
            ++$counts.jobs
        }
        elseif ($run.job | % $isTask) {
            ++$counts.tasks
        }
        #if we weren't given a [Job] we need to spawn it for them
        elseif ($run.job -is [ScriptBlock]) {
            $pwsh=[powershell]::Create().AddScript($run.job)
            $run.args | %{ $pwsh.AddArgument($_) } | Out-Null
            $pwsh.RunspacePool=$pool
            $run.job=$pwsh.AddParameters($run.params).BeginInvoke(
                [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[PSObject]]::new(
                    [PSObject[]]($run.input)
                )
            )
            $run.job | Add-Member `
                -MemberType NoteProperty `
                -Name pwsh `
                -Value $pwsh `
                -PassThru `
            | Add-Member `
                -MemberType NoteProperty `
                -Name Id `
                -Value $run.job.AsyncWaitHandle.Handle.ToString()
            ++$counts.results
        }
        else {
            throw "$($run.job.GetType()) needs to be a ScriptBlock"
        }

        $running.Add($run.job.Id, $run) | Out-Null
    }

    End {
        #wait for the remaining running processes
        $BatchSize=1
        Wait -Finishing
        Write-Progress -Id $asyncId -Activity $Name -Completed
        $pool.Close()
        $pool.Dispose()
    }
}
```

---

So you may have noticed three things above, I alluded to `-AsJob` (using a mix of `Job`s, `Task`s and `scriptblock`s), there are unused protocols mentioned in the test data, and the video had a third test in it.

Here it is. Instead of doing the basic tcp test, using the test data we will also do a http/s check and a icmp ping (idk, maybe the https fails, but you want to narrow down if it's because the machine is down or just the service).

- [`Test-Connection -AsJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-5.1#parameters) is a cmdlet that returns a `Job` and checks ping.
- [`WebRequest.GetResponseAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync?view=netframework-4.8) which connects to a web resource, returning a `Task`
- And finally [`Test-NetConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=win10-ps), which will be the same as before, ran in what we programmed as a synchronous scriptblock, which will be ran asynchronously for us.

```powershell
$in=TestData
$in `
| Async `
    -Expected $in.Count `
    -PassThru `
    -AsJob `
    <#this would be accessible as a named parameter if needed#>`
    -Parameters @{proxy=[System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()} `
    -Func { Param([parameter(Position=0)]$x)
        $x.job=Switch -regex ($x.input.proto) {
            '^icmp$' {
                Test-Connection `
                    -ComputerName $x.input.address `
                    -Count 1 `
                    -ThrottleLimit 1 `
                    -AsJob
            }

            '^tcp$' {
                $x.params=@{address=$x.input.address; port=$x.input.port}
                { Param($address, $port)
                    $WarningPreference='SilentlyContinue'
                    Test-NetConnection `
                        -ComputerName $address `
                        -Port $port `
                        -InformationLevel Quiet
                }
            }

            '^(http|https)$' {
                [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
                $request=[System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create((@(
                    $x.input.proto,
                    '://',
                    $x.input.address,
                    ':',
                    $x.input.port
                ) -join ''))
                $request.Proxy=$NULL
                $request.Method='Get'
                $request.GetResponseAsync()
            }
        }
    } `
| %{
    $result=$_
    $result.input `
    | Add-Member `
        -PassThru `
        -MemberType NoteProperty `
        -Name result `
        -Value $(Switch -regex (@($result.input.proto, $result.job.message)[$result.job -is [Exception]]) {
            #[Win32_PingStatus]
            '^icmp$' { $result.job.StatusCode -eq 0 }

            #[bool]
            '^tcp$' { $result.job }

            #[System.Net.HttpWebResponse]
            '^(http|https)$' {
                $result.job.Close()
                Switch ($result.job.StatusCode.value__) {
                    { $_ -ge 200 -and $_ -lt 400 } { $True }
                    Default {$False}
                }
            }

            #[Exception]
            Default { $False }
        })
} `
| Timer -name 'async asjob' `
| Format-Table
```

As you may have seen, this did more than double the work of the original code, but still finished in around half the time at 8seconds.

[image]