# Multi-thread powershell script with different arguments

Tags: multithreading, powershell, optimization

I'm trying to run a Powershell script that pulls data from an APM device across a date range. However it can take up to 9 hours for a week date range. When I run it in a for loop day by date, it takes 35 minutes:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $dateList.Length-1; $i++){
    & "C:\Scripts\Grabber.ps1" -date  $dateList[$i] -date2 $dateList[$i+1]
}
```

I need to optimize that further. I've looked at [PoshRSJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) and [Invoke-Parallel](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Run-Parallel-Parallel-377fd430), but I can't seem to get my head around this! I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: so whats the problem? I'd definitely go with Runspaces for that

Comment: @4c74356b41 can you recommend a resource? Tried technet but I get a syntax error: [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/26/beginning-use-of-powershell-runspaces-part-1/)

error: "An expression was expected after '('."
code:$Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$PowerShell = ::Create()
$PowerShell.runspace = $Runspace
$Runspace.Open()

[void]$PowerShell.AddScript({

    Get-Date

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

})

$AsyncObject = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()

Comment: Nah, I mean PoshRSJob, unless you want to reinvent the wheel

Comment: To clarify: I want to run the Grabber.ps1 everyday for 7 days. Each day will have to invoke the grabber.ps1 script in parallel. Does that make sense?

Comment: @4c74356b41 ok thanks. How do I invoke the script and pass in date values as parameters? I can only see examples of script blocks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766174/how-to-execute-a-powershell-function-several-times-in-parallel#12768438

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a Powershell function several times in parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766174/how-to-execute-a-powershell-function-several-times-in-parallel)

Answer (score 0):

Well, just include your script in the scriptblock?

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $dateList.Length-1; $i++){
    start-rsjob -name {$_} -ScriptBlock {
        & "C:\Scripts\Grabber.ps1" -date  ($using:dateList)[$using:i] -date2 ($using:dateList)[$using:i+1] 
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a slow Monday.. cheers. However now I get a "expression is not allowed inside a using expression" on the $i variable. I just passed in a date as a string and the script executes, but isn't running as it should. It doesn't even hit the print statement at the top of the grabber.ps1 script. Any ideas?

Comment: well, reassign $i and $datelist inside scriptblock to new variables, and use them

Comment: 1) You should `$using:i` as well. 2) You should use parenthesis to not cause parse error: `($using:dateList)[$using:i]`.